# Continuous function sur unit circle

Tags: calculus

I have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to S$, where $S$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ (all complex numbers with norm $1$). I intend to prove that I can characterize $f$ by some continuous angle function $\theta$, i.e. $f = \exp(i\theta)$. The intuition is straightforward that we add $2\pi$ when the argument changes from $2\pi^-$ to $0$ and minus it when this happens in the other direction.

But for a strict proof, I could only show it when $f$ is $C^1$. I could first define its "angular velocity" and then calculate the integral. But in the $C^0$ case, I haven't figured out how to define the "direction" exactly to get rid of the discontinuity of the argument.

Comment: You can just as easily: $v(\theta) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, which is the parametric equation of a unit circle, this is easy to see as $|v|^2 = x^2 + y^2 = \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$.

Comment: You can apply Theorem 7.6.2 of "A Course in Probability Theory' by K L Chung.